# Decision Trees - Scikit, Python

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to create a decision tree based on some training data. I have never created a decision tree before, but have completed a few linear regression models. I have 3 questions:

1. With linear regression I find it fairly easy to plot graphs, fit models, group factor levels, check P statistics etc. in an iterative fashion until I end up with a good predictive model. I have no idea how to evaluate a decision tree. Is there a way to get a summary of the model, (for example, .summary() function in statsmodels)? Should this be an iterative process where I decide whether a factor is significant - if so how can I tell?
2. I have been very unsuccessful in visualising the decision tree. On the various different ways I have tried, the code seems to run without any errors, yet nothing appears / plots. The only thing I can do successfully is `tree.export_text(model)`, which just states feature_1, feature_2, and so on. I don't know what any of the features actually are. Has anybody come across these difficulties with visualising / have a simple solution?
3. The confusion matrix that I have generated is as follows:

   ```
   [[   0  395]
    [   0 3319]]
   ```

i.e. the model is predicting all rows to the same outcome. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Scikit-learn is a library designed to build predictive models, so there are no tests of significance, confidence intervals, etc. You can always build your own statistics, but this is a tedious process. In scikit-learn, you can eliminate features recursively using RFE, RFECV, etc. You can find a list of [feature selection algorithms here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.feature_importances_). For the most part, these algorithms get rid off the least important feature in each loop according to [`feature_importances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.feature_importances_) (where the importance of each feature is defined as its contribution to the reduction in entropy, gini, etc.).
2. The most straight forward way to [visualize a tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) is `tree.plot_tree()`.  In particular, you should try passing the names of the features to `feature_names`. Please show us what you have tried so far if you want a more specific answer.
3. Try another `criterion`, set a higher `max_depth`, etc. Sometimes datasets have unidentifiable records. For example, two observations with the exact same values in all features, but different target labels. Is this the case in your dataset?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. 1. Ok, so am I right in thinking the algorithms make the decisions about significance by themselves? If so, what is the best way to evaluate the model? 2. Thanks, I managed to get tree.plot_tree() to work, do X[11], X[10],... etc refer to the index of the column names in my training data? 3. Yes, this is the case. Thinking about it now, is this a common problem with decision trees? Do the factors have to be highly predictive / clearcut in order for decision trees to spit out good results?

Comment: 1. Sklearn algorithms don't make decisions based on significance levels. Predictors are selected if they reduce the cost function regardless of their p-value. A popular method is to compare the AUC on `x_train` and `x_test` to decide if you should drop a feature. This is more generally known as cross-validation. 2. Yes, the feature names go in the same order as the features in `x_train`. 3. Yes, this happens because trees are a bunch of if-else splits. If you can't create heterogeneous groups by splitting your variables in two, then a decision tree is probably not a good idea.